# The system can't find specify file when using iis to broswer home.aspx file?

Tags: c#

I write a asp.net website,but when i brower it in iis,and it tips:

```
 Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: system can't find specify file。

Source error: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system can't find specify file.]

[SqlException (0x80131904): an instance error associate with network occured when link to SQL Server .Can't find or access to server.Please verify instance name is correct and SQL Server aready configurationa remote link  avaliable . (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - can't open SQL Server linker)]
   EcaClient.ECAService.EcaClientService.GetUserModulePermission(Int32 userId, String moduleType) +120
   EcaPortal.CSNavigation.GetCurrentUserModule() in E:\CucEcaPortal\CSNavigation.aspx.cs:113
   EcaPortal.CSNavigation.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\CucEcaPortal\CSNavigation.aspx.cs:26
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

This is what i aready do:

```
1.Check the connection string,it is aready correct.

2.reconfiguration  the portal in iis.

3.give the portal folder read/write privillege to everyone.  

4.restart the iis

5.Search the error from internet if has any usable suggestion.
```

PS:Yesterday my website is correct and can broswer normal.

the `w3wp.exe` aways show form and needed visual 2010 to let me debug.

And when i check the process the `w3wp.exe` using a user name like:`Default app pool`,is it normal?

Why the iis find path from other location?

My aspx file location is:

```
E:\appserver\service\CucEcaPortal\CSNavigation.aspx.cs
```

but it just find from

```
E:\CucEcaPortal\CSNavigation.aspx.cs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply follow these steps,you will get rid to this error:

```
1.Reset IIS (Start>Run>IIsreset.exe)
2.Clear Cache (Ctrl+Shift+Delete Then Click Clear Now)
3.Clear Temporary File(Start>Run>%Temp% Then Enter,and Delete all Files)
4.Recycle your Website In IIs 
5.Stop/Start SQL Servies( Start>Control Panel>Administrative Panel>Services>Sql Server(Sql Express))
```

and you will Definitely get rid from this error.